# Swipe left to right LI without scroll CSS or JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to swipe `LI` from left to right in mobile and I have done it simply with `CSS`, I know it can be easily done with any plugin, but I cannot use any plugin in my project, Here is the [JSfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/3rfhf4aL/) what I have created, the main requirement is, to remove that scrollbar from bottom, in mobile that scrollbar appear when you touch the content area.

If I am making the parent div `overflow:hidden` then I cant swipe.

```css
.spotlight_numbers-v2 {
width: 100%;
max-width: 480px;
float: left;
background: #f3f3f3;
overflow: auto;
}
.spotlight_numbers-v2 > ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 150%;
}
.spotlight_numbers-v2 > ul > li {
color: #606060;
font-weight: 500;
display: inline-block;
list-style: none;
margin: 0 15px;
padding: 10px;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 16px;
}
.spotlight_numbers-v2 > ul > li > a {
color: #606060;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="spotlight_numbers-v2">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Doctors</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Hospital</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Drugs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Interview</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use another container and give it a height smaller than the height of the `.spotlight_numbers-v2` and set the container to `overflow: hidden;`.

```css
.container{
   height: 40px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.spotlight_numbers-v2 {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 480px;
  float: left;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.spotlight_numbers-v2 > ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 150%;
}
.spotlight_numbers-v2 > ul > li {
  color: #606060;
  font-weight: 500;
  display: inline-block;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.spotlight_numbers-v2 > ul > li > a {
  color: #606060;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="spotlight_numbers-v2">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Doctors</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Hospital</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Articles</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Drugs</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Interview</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: try to inspect it and see in mobile view so you can see that it still scrollable when swiped from right-left.

Comment: Its good for now, but I think I will have to with the javascript method to achieve this.